# What is the idiomatic way to convert an Array of Dict to a DataFrame

Tags: dictionary, dataframe, julia

I'm trying to convert an `Array` of `Dict` to a `DataFrame`. What is the idiomatic way to do this.

```
using HTTP, JSON

function getBody(resp)
    jsonb=String(resp.body)
    bodyData = JSON.parse(jsonb)
end

function histoday()
    base_url="https://min-api.cryptocompare.com"
    path= "data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=100"
    url="$base_url/$path"
    bd = getBody(HTTP.get(url))["Data"]
end

histoday()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be

```
x = histoday()
vcat(DataFrame.(x)...)
```

Comment: Note that it is not the most performant way though. But probably this doesn't matter for your use case.

Comment: I guess that'd be one avoiding the intermediate DataFrame allocations. I.e. creating one and then pushing into the existing one.